# How do I convert Hours in decimal (1.25) to minutes (75) for a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, type-conversion

I tried

```
UPDATE Datsta SET Datsta.SCHED_TIME_MIN = SCHED_TIME * 60, AS decimal(5,2);
```

where SCHED_TIME_MIN is the new converted field in minutes and SCHED_TIME is in hours

```
|SCHED_TIME ||  SCHED_TIME_MIN| 
|    7.28   ||                |
|    1.00   ||                | 
|    4.45   ||                |    the table name is Datsta
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do:

```
UPDATE Datsta
    SET SCHED_TIME_MIN = SCHED_TIME * 60;
```

The `cast()` should be unnecessary, but if you really want it:

```
UPDATE Datsta
    SET SCHED_TIME_MIN = CAST(SCHED_TIME * 60 as DECIMAL(5, 2));
```

Note:  I removed the qualifier in the `SET`.  You don't specify your database.  It is unnecessary and not all versions of SQL support a qualifier for the column being set.

Comment: it didn't output a value

Comment: What database are you using?  Does it generate an error?  What is the data type for `SCHED_TIME`?

Comment: I"m using Access .it doesn't generate an error and the data type is a number.

Comment: @ShengTan . . . The first version should work in Access.  An `update` statement doesn't output anything; you need to do `select * from Datsta` to see any changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do

Just `SET SCHED_TIME_MIN = SCHED_TIME * 60;`

As you multiply, Hour to 60 so , it will automatically convert to minute

For Ex:- 
SCHED_TIME = 2 Then MIn = 2* 60 = 120

SCHED_TIME = 2.5 Then MIn = 2.5* 60 = 150

SCHED_TIME = 1.25 Then MIn = 1.25* 60 = 75

Comment: that's what I did, but it didn't output anything

Comment: try to remove this qualifier      Datsta.  after SET keyword

Comment: can you include table structure with datatype

Comment: Edit your question, and just add your Table definition

Comment: It says i don't have reputation points to sent images, how else other than typing it out

Comment: you have only table, just Edit your question, and manually type your table definition